# Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 'BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE has exited with code 1 (0x1)'

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create a scheduled task agent for my windows phone application. I followed this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202941%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). But it seemed that the backgroud task exited wrongly. Here are some details:

1. I have two projects in my solution: `TestApp (Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1)` and `ScheduledTaskAgent1 (Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1)`.
2. I have added the `ScheduledTaskAgent1` as a reference of `TestApp`.
3. I have added the code below to `WMAppManifest.xml` in `TestApp`:

   ```
   <Tasks>
     <DefaultTask Name ="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume"/>
     <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
       <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="ScheduledTaskAgent1" Source="ScheduledTaskAgent1" Type="ScheduledTaskAgent1.ScheduledAgent" />
     </ExtendedTask>
   </Tasks>
   ```
4. In my `MainPage.xaml.cs` in `TestApp`, I have the following code:

   ```
   private async void StartPeriodicTask()
   {
       periodicTask = ScheduledActionService.Find(periodicTaskName) as PeriodicTask;
       if (periodicTask != null)
       {
           try
           {
               ScheduledActionService.Remove(periodicTaskName);
           }
           catch (System.Exception)
           {
           }
       }

       periodicTask = new PeriodicTask(periodicTaskName);
       periodicTask.Description = "Lock Screen Image Changing Task";
       periodicTask.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);

       try
       {
           ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Periodic task added.");
   #if(DEBUG_AGENT)
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Starting debugging");
           ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Periodic task is started: " + periodicTaskName);
   #endif
       }
       catch (InvalidOperationException e)
       {
           if (e.Message.Contains("BNS Error: The action is disabled"))
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Background agents for this application have been disabled by the user.");
           }
       }
       catch (SchedulerServiceException)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Periodic task added failed.");
       }
   } /* void StartPeriodicTask() */
   ```
5. In my `ScheduledAgent.cs` in `ScheduledTaskAgent1`, I have the following **simple** code:

   ```
   protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
   {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Background task accomplished.");
       NotifyComplete();   
   } /* OnInvoke() */
   ```

   Other code in `ScheduledAgent.cs` kept unchanged as it was created automatcally by VS2013.
6. After I started the program and called `StartPeriodicTask()`, I got these outputs:

   ```
   'BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
   'BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
   'BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
   'BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
   'BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
   'BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
   'BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{8BF294CB-9B46-4BD1-84A7-58C60582A35C}\Install\TestApp.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
   'BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
   'BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
   'BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{8BF294CB-9B46-4BD1-84A7-58C60582A35C}\Install\ScheduledTaskAgent1.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
   Background task accomplished.
   The program '[0xCF0] BACKGROUNDTASKHOST.EXE' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
   ```

   The last two lines showed the `OnInvoke()` method was called but the task exited wrongly.

So, how can I make the background task exits correctly?

Any reply will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942340/backgroundtaskhost-exe-has-exited-with-code-1-0x1-geofence-issue or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988200/backgroundtaskhost-exe-exits-with-code-1-0x1

Comment: @igrali, sure! Of course I have read it. And he setted a background task in another way, but if I use `Windows Runtime Component` to build a background task, I cannot using LockScreenManger and some other lock screen api.

Comment: Any Solution on above issue. I am struggling for the same. If anyone have answer please update.

Comment: Had the same issue. Follow this link on how to add a project reference  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx
Your Runtime Component must be listed under "References" of your Windows Phone Project